# Videoview is not playing .3gp file

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp

I am trying to play .3gp file from a live RTSP. following is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
//  String path = "rtsp://v5.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnhycnrJQ8qmRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYPj_hYjnq6uUTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";
    String path = "rtsp://217.146.95.166:554/live/ch12zqcif.3gp";

    VideoView videoView = null; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));       
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();

        if ( videoView != null )
        {
            videoView.pause(); 
            videoView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have given INTERNET Permission in my AnroidManifest.xml file.

When I load the first path variable with Youtube one, it is working file and loading the video but the second RTSP url is not working.

What could be the problem for this..?

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with you is your `URL` please verify the `rtsp` url. Here is the example for [how to playvideo with the `videoview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871180/how-to-play-video-which-is-at-some-url-location-in-androids-video-view).

Cheers

Comment: The url I used is not from youtube, see my second `path` variable

Comment: have you put your video in that url, coz when i use your url i got the search page, but it should show the video on browser.

Comment: How did you do that ?

Comment: I just copied and paste in my browser url. you can see the example, copy the url which is used in that example paste it in your browser, and also paste your url in other browser and see the difference.

Comment: You can not view these url in browser,

Comment: Have you generated the right `url` this is the only problem because your code is looking fine.

Comment: rtsp://r5---sn-a5m7zu7l.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkjsfwsgWXg_BMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp use this url is it working tell me if it works

Comment: It says can't play this video :( , which I think some spelling mistake in url.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44262/discussion-between-vigbyor-and-user3110424)

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/YourVideoId use this url to generate your rtsp link replace the `YourVideoId` with your video id